# File last modified time and current time

Tags: java, time, java-7

-I am not using java 8 (Date+Time API...)-I am using Java SE 7

What I am trying to accomplish here is get the last modified time of the directories inside a parent directory in miliseconds , get the current time of the system in miliseconds and then compare them (and delete if...)

This does not seem to work though..

Code:

```
private void deleteFolders(int sec) {

    int counter = 0;

    File subf[] = MyParentDirectory.listFiles();    

    for(File f : subf){
        if(f.isDirectory()){
        if((Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MILLISECOND) - (f.lastModified() + 1000)) > sec){//The comparison
        f.delete();
        System.out.print("Deleted " + f.getName() + "\n");
        counter++;
        }   
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Deleted " + counter + " out of " + subf.length +" folders" + "\n");

}
```

Comment: You appear to be getting the current millisecond value, rather than the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Use date.getTime instead, and store the result in a variable rather than calculating it each time.

Comment: @Dave how am I supposed to instantiate a Date object?(Contructor params)

Comment: Use no params and it will default to the current time

Comment: http://prntscr.com/3hxakn see?

Comment: Are you importing `java.util.Date` or some other library?

Comment: @Dave I changed it to the util one and it still doesnt work. I also used System.currentTimeMillis() and Calendar.getInstance.getTime

Comment: You'll have to define "doesn't work". Is it deleting the wrong things? Try logging the individual values and check where it goes awry. Looking at your code and the changes we discussed, I can't see a problem.

Comment: Oh except that your calculations are in milliseconds yet you have a parameter named "sec"; maybe you expected it to be in seconds? Try multiplying that variable by 1000 before using it.

Comment: @Dave I used the system.curr.... and it worked. A simple int cast needed to be removed , make an answer and ill approove it

Comment: Ah yes, times should always be stored in `long`s to avoid rollover. Anyway this was more of a discussion; no need for an explicit answer (tends not to be useful to future visitors when things diverge from the original question)

Answer (score 0):

It look like, there is some problem with File#lastModified() on my Windows, perhaps it is same for you. Try this:

```
private long getSecondsFromModification(File f) throws IOException {
    Path attribPath = f.toPath();
    BasicFileAttributes basicAttribs
            = Files.readAttributes(attribPath, BasicFileAttributes.class);
    return (System.currentTimeMillis()
            - basicAttribs.lastModifiedTime().to(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
            / 1000;
}


private void deleteFolders(int sec) {

    int counter = 0;
    File subf[] = myParentDirectory.listFiles();

    for (File f : subf) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            try {
                if (getSecondsFromModification(f) > sec) {
                    f.delete();
                    System.out.print("Deleted " + f.getName() + "\n");
                    counter++;
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Unable to access file " + f.getName() + " informtaion");
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Deleted " + counter + " out of " + subf.length + " folders" + "\n");
}
```